# ms bot service, Is it possible to update both text and attachments? Encounter with `Activity resulted into multiple skype activities`

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I have a demand to update past chat items which is send to bot.
I use the following API to update activity.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#update-activity

I successfully updated the message when I request like this.

```
~~~ REQUEST ~~~
PUT  /jp/v3/conversations/conversationID/activities/activityID HTTP/1.1
HOST   : smba.trafficmanager.net
HEADERS:
    Accept: application/json;charset=utf-8
    Authorization: Bearer Token
    Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
    User-Agent: go-resty/2.3.0 (https://github.com/go-resty/resty)
BODY   :
{
   "text": "lllllll\u003cp\u003e\u003cbr\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\\n\u003cdiv\u003e\u003cimg width=\"386\" height=\"476\" src=\"https://host.jp.ngrok.io/api/v1/images?item_id=01TPIDETFC2MITU7PJFJHYUZEZYJBOMWCL\u0026group_id=f64dd886-4edf-4b23-8f51-c6720042807d\u0026token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJib3RfaWQiOjEsImdyb3VwX2lkIjoiZjY0ZGQ4ODYtNGVkZi00YjIzLThmNTEtYzY3MjAwNDI4MDdkIiwiaXRlbV9pZCI6IjAxVFBJREVURkMyTUlUVTdQSkZKSFlVWkVaWUpCT01XQ0wiLCJhdWQiOiJ3b3JrcGxhY2UuYmVkb3JlLmpwIiwiaWF0IjoxNjY0MzQzNDg2LCJpc3MiOiJ3b3JrcGxhY2UuYmVkb3JlLmpwIiwibmJmIjoxNjY0MzQzNDg2fQ.MZKEurQeBqP71iEcdxuiG342ZDvhMZ-QxqYnJYvbhmM\"/\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\\n\u003cp\u003e\u003cbr\u003e\u003c/p\u003e",
   "type": "message",
   "id": "1664769144846"
}
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
~~~ RESPONSE ~~~
STATUS       : 200 OK
PROTO        : HTTP/1.1
RECEIVED AT  : 2022-10-03T15:30:50.642248+09:00
TIME DURATION: 434.921ms
HEADERS      :
    Content-Length: 22
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Date: Mon, 03 Oct 2022 06:30:49 GMT
    Ms-Cv: QxMPXxpyPk2IcBQOtkyErA.0
    Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
BODY         :
{
   "id": "1664769144846"
}
```

And I failed when I request like this.

```
2022/10/03 15:32:45.241320 DEBUG RESTY 
==============================================================================
~~~ REQUEST ~~~
PUT  /jp/v3/conversations/conversationID/activities/activityID  HTTP/1.1
HOST   : smba.trafficmanager.net
HEADERS:
    Accept: application/json;charset=utf-8
    Authorization: Bearer Token
    Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
    User-Agent: go-resty/2.3.0 (https://github.com/go-resty/resty)
BODY   :
{
   "text": "lllllll\u003cp\u003e\u003cbr\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\\n\u003cdiv\u003e\u003cimg width=\"386\" height=\"476\" src=\"https://host.jp.ngrok.io/api/v1/images?item_id=01TPIDETFC2MITU7PJFJHYUZEZYJBOMWCL\u0026group_id=f64dd886-4edf-4b23-8f51-c6720042807d\u0026token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJib3RfaWQiOjEsImdyb3VwX2lkIjoiZjY0ZGQ4ODYtNGVkZi00YjIzLThmNTEtYzY3MjAwNDI4MDdkIiwiaXRlbV9pZCI6IjAxVFBJREVURkMyTUlUVTdQSkZKSFlVWkVaWUpCT01XQ0wiLCJhdWQiOiJ3b3JrcGxhY2UuYmVkb3JlLmpwIiwiaWF0IjoxNjY0MzQzNDg2LCJpc3MiOiJ3b3JrcGxhY2UuYmVkb3JlLmpwIiwibmJmIjoxNjY0MzQzNDg2fQ.MZKEurQeBqP71iEcdxuiG342ZDvhMZ-QxqYnJYvbhmM\"/\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\\n\u003cp\u003e\u003cbr\u003e\u003c/p\u003e",
   "type": "message",
   "id": "1664769144846",
   "attachments": [
      {
         "contentType": "image/png",
         "contentUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/750",
         "name": "placeholder"
      }
   ]
}
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
~~~ RESPONSE ~~~
STATUS       : 400 Bad Request
PROTO        : HTTP/1.1
RECEIVED AT  : 2022-10-03T15:32:45.241272+09:00
TIME DURATION: 84.414125ms
HEADERS      :
    Content-Length: 91
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Date: Mon, 03 Oct 2022 06:32:44 GMT
    Ms-Cv: kn6QMv/UH0iJhMXfL0s1HA.0
    Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
BODY         :
{
   "error": {
      "code": "BadSyntax",
      "message": "Activity resulted into multiple skype activities"
   }
}
```

**It looks that it is impossible to update text and attachments at the same time.** It is necessary for us to update both text and attachments within one request for sending only attachments will erase text info.

Does anyone know the reason about `**Activity resulted into multiple skype activities**`?

[image]

Comment: What did the original message contain? Trying to update a message that contained only text with text and an image may not be supported.

Comment: @AP01
Hi, the both is failed
1. only text
2. text and attachments

Comment: @AP01 Both only text and text with attachments in original message will fail if i want to patch with text and attachments body

Comment: It possible then that Teams doesn't support this scenario. I'll look into it further.

Comment: It looks like Teams might not support this. If you add the `microsoft-teams` tag to your question, Teams experts may jump in.